# What kind of encryption does Firebase Authentication SDK provide for iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Basically, I'm using Firebase authentication SDK in my iOS app to provide secure login to users and trying to upload the app to TestFlight.  Upon upload, I'm seeing this question below that asks if the app uses cryptography but then there are exceptions where some cryptography algorithms are exempted?  Please advise on how to answer in regards to using Firebase Auth SDK.

Thank you!

"Is your product designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?

Please answer “YES” to the question even if your app uses or accesses encryption from another source, e.g., iOS or Mac OS X.

If your application does not use, access, implement or incorporate encryption, you can answer “NO” to this question and you can continue with the process of uploading your binary.

If your application does use, access, implement or incorporate encryption, it may be necessary to submit confirmation of approval by the United States Government and an approval from French authorities if your app is going to be distributed in France."

Comment: As a heads up, this question is off-topic for SO - this is a site about programming and coding issues and your question is really about server capabilities. It's not a bad question, it's just not a good question for this site. You should reach out to Firebase directly for this info or check out the Firebase google group. Since you are new here, please see [Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase Auth SDK does not currently make use of cryptography on the client. The SDK is now open source on github, please feel free to take a look at the source code.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk

Comment: has this been always the case or has changed since a certain version/release?  Thank you much!

Comment: This has been the case for recent versions.